Filtering data by matching values in Matlab
I have 2 data sets in Matlab, each one is a 2xn array of data, where the top row contains timestamps. However, not each timestamp has a data point. Now I want to compare these datapoints, but I cannot use the index without filtering any data points that are not mutual. So to give an example:
A = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6;
      3, 4, 5, 7, 8 ]

B = [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6;
      9, 8, 6, 5, 4 ]

I want to use some kind of operation or set of operations to end up with
A = [1, 2, 5, 6;
     3, 4, 7, 8 ]

B = [ 1, 2, 5, 6;
      9, 8, 5, 4 ]

So that the times and datapoints match the indexes.
I have used ismember to identify the indexes that are not mutual, but I'm having trouble deleting the offending columns from the original set. I multiplied the ismember output with the dataset, but all it does is set the timestamps in the columns to zero.

You can get the common timestamps, then filter A and B for columns with timestamps in this array
t = intersect( A(1,:), B(1,:) ); % Get common timestamps
A = A( :, ismember(A(1,:), t) ); % Only retain cols with timestamps in common array
B = B( :, ismember(B(1,:), t) ); % Only retain cols with timestamps in common array


Alternatively, you could just remove columns from A where the timestamp isn't in B, and then vice versa:
A( :, ~ismember(A(1,:),B(1,:)) ) = []; % Remove A cols not in B's timestamps
B( :, ~ismember(B(1,:),A(1,:)) ) = []; % Remove B cols not in A's timestamps

